# What is the alternative for CollabNet's python svn bindings?

Tags: python, windows, svn, python-bindings

What is the alternative for the **python svn bindings** provided by **CollabNet** (this where you have 2 directories: *svn* and *libsvn*, the second with a lot of pre-compiled libraries)? The problem with it is that it just can't be configured to run with Windows version on Python. We've done what was written on various fora, but it just didn't work.

At best would be the package written fully in python - no compilation issues. I know of **pysvn**, but it seems to have client-side functionality (based on checkouted code) not server-side (based on provided repository path, such as **svnlook**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Subversion is written in C and provides native libraries for the OS.  On Windows, this means DLL's.  Subversion provides "bindings" for a number of different languages, including Python.  This gives you a shim that lets you write code in your language and the bindings handle making calls into the native libraries.

To use the Python bindings, you need to install them into your Python system but you ALSO need to make sure the appropriate Subversion native library are on PATH.  Your Python code will load the Python bindings, but that code will load and make calls into the native DLL's.  So they have to be on the PATH and they have to be a matching version.

There is no "pure Python" version of Subversion.

Comment: When you say "install them into your Python system", could you be more specific? Do they go into `\python\lib\<something>` or \python\libs\<something>` or somewhere else, and I have to add an ENV variable?

Comment: The Python bindings go into the site-packages folder.  ISTR, that is a child of the lib folder.  In terms of PATH, that needs to include whatever folder the main SVN executables and DLL's are installed in.

Comment: Thanks. I just guessed it went into `site-packages`, and it turned out I was right. :)